# How to undo a merge that has been committed already and other merges have been done after that also

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I have a branch (`Branch5`) that I need to undo that was merged into another branch (`Branch2`), but since than, `Branch3`, `Branch4`, and `Branch6` have also been merged into `Branch2`.  How do I just unmerge the `Branch5` that was merged into `Branch2`?

Hopefully that makes sense.  `Branch2` basically has everything I need minus `Branch5`, but `Branch5` was merged into `Branch2` a few merges/commits ago and has already been pushed as well.  Basically, how do I revert it so that it has everything in `Branch2` from all branches, except `Branch5`?

So, doing a search reveals the following...

`git revert -m 1 hash_of_merge_commit`

How do I get the hash of a merge?  Also, what does the `1` after `-m` mean here?  And finally, will this actually work?

Comment: An ASCII graph of your repo, even a simplified one, would help. In particular, does `Branch5` still exist, or has it been deleted?

Comment: Yes `Branch5` still exists, does that mean I can use `git diff` somehow?

Comment: Also, have you committed anything on `Branch5` since you merged it into `Branch2`?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure.  It is possible... :(  Though, I don't think so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How do I get the hash of the merge commit of interest?

Without knowing more about the state of your repo (in particular, where `Branch5` is, at the moment), identifying the SHA of the merge of `Branch5` into `Branch2` is going to be difficult. However, running

```
git log --oneline --merges Branch2
```

will limit the log to merge commits that are reachable from `Branch2`, which should allow you to easily identify (thanks to the commit message) the hash of the commit of interest.

### What does the `1` after `-m` mean here?

To illustrate things, consider the following graphs:

#### Right before the merge of `Branch5` into `Branch2`

```
... -- o -- A [HEAD=Branch2]

   ... -- o -- B [Branch5]
```

#### Right after the merge of `Branch5` into `Branch2`

```
... -- o -- A -- C [HEAD=Branch2]
                /
   ... -- o -- B [Branch5]
```

#### Some later time

```
... -- o -- A -- C -- o -- ... -- o -- o [HEAD=Branch2]
                /
   ... -- o -- B [Branch5]
```

Reverting commit `C` means creating a new commit (let's call it `Z`) undoing the changes that occured between one of `C`'s parents and `C` itself. Because `C` is a merge commit, it has several (two, here) parents, so you need to tell `git revert` which changes, from `A` to `C` or from `B` to `C`, you actually want to undo.

That's where the `-m` option comes in; it stands for `--parent-number`, and you can find more detail about the `-m` option in the `git-revert` man page. In a simple merge of one branch into another,

- the first parent is the head of the checked out branch (before the merge),
- the second parent is the head of the branch being merged in,

Here, `A` is the first parent of `C`, and `B` is the second parent of `C`. You want to undo the changes between `A` and `C`; therefore, you need to run

```
git revert -m 1 C
```

### Will this actually work?

That revert operation may give rise to conflicts, which you will have to resolve, but it should, in effect, undo the merge of `Branch5` into `Branch2`, as desired.

```
... -- o -- A -- C -- o -- ... -- o -- o -- Z [HEAD=Branch2]
                /
   ... -- o -- B [Branch5]
```

Comment: After I remove `Branch5`, `Branch2` will be perfect and it will not be needed anymore after it gets merged into `master`. that `git rev-list` code just spit out a ton of hash codes, nothing but hash codes...

Comment: @SolomonClosson Sorry, I meant `git log --oneline --merges Branch2`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I think what happened was, the branch was created within another branch as it's starting point, and this caused an issue because that branch needed to go live today, and the other branch was for more long-term updates....  Anyways, it's fixed now, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So your command you have up there is correct, the way you get the hash of a commit is by using `git log`.  As part of each log entry, the hash of the commit is located there as well.  Just enter that in as the hash, or at least the first few characters, and it will work.

Comment: I think I need the hash of the merge, not the commit.  How to get the merge hash code?

Comment: git log is giving me commits from 10 days ago.  I just now merged something into `Branch2` and pushed it via `git push origin Branch2`, but it is not showing that merge, why?